# Can't use "browser.storage.session" and can't find why either. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, local-storage, session-storage

I am developing an extension which uses both **storage.local** and **storage.session** but session is not working and I can't find why it isn't working neither googling it or in the firefox documentation.

I have this on a background script (*content_scripts/test_storage.js*):

```
browser.storage.local.set({"local":"example_local"});
browser.storage.session.set({"session":"example_session"});
```

Which results in the local storage being set but the session stroage yielding and error **"Uncaught TypeError: browser.storage.session is undefined"**:
[image: result]

This is part of the manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "webNavigation",
    
    "storage",

    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "<all_urls>", 

    "notifications",
    "tabs"
],
"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "content_scripts/test_storage.js"
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something? Is storage.session not allowed? Or what is it that yields the error?

Answer (score 0):

As per MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/session#browser_compatibility at the time of writing Chromium supports session storage and Firefox does not

You'll have to emulate session storage by instead using local storage and adding listeners for `browser.runtime.onStartup`, `browser.runtime.onSuspend`, `browser.runtime.onInstalled` etcetera that will clear your 'session' storage data.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on Firefox 121. storage.session is supposed to be supported as of Firefox 115. (released a few months after your answer)